# For loop to list users in /etc/passwd file

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to echo user, shell and home fields from /etc/passwd file using a for loop. What I am trying is to use:

`IFS=:` IFS Separator
`read -r user pass desc home shell` for storing fields in these variable then print them.

I can use while loop instead, but I would like to use FOR loop. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are most likely going to get down-voted for not showing any start, effort, or problem you are running into.  Why a "for" loop, there are better ways IMO.  You should share your goal.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: If you **just** want to print user, shell, and home fields (in this order) and nothing else, why don't you just do: `awk -F ':' '{print "user: "$1" shell: "$7" home: "$6}' /etc/passwd` ?

Comment: No, in this case you must use a `while` loop. A `for` loop requires that you know what you're iterating over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you *can't* use a `for`-loop as you don't know how much input you will get. A `for`-loop is "static" in the sense that the shell needs to know exactly what it's iterating over when it gets to it.

You could bypass this through actually reading in the whole file (and in that way get to know exactly what to iterate over) and then `for`-looping over that data, but it would be rather clunky.

The "correct" way is to `read` in a `while`-loop:

```
IFS=':'
while read -r user pass uid gid desc home shell; do
  echo "User is '$user', has shell '$shell'"
done </etc/passwd
```

Comment: Got the point, i know i can accomplish using while loop, however i wanted to test "for loop". Thank you all for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally `read`s are paired with `while` loops.  Intuitively this makes sense: you normally want to continue reading while there's more data to be read.  Such a loop usually looks like:

```
while IFS=: read -r user pass desc home shell; do
    echo "$user has home $home, uses $shell"
done < /etc/passwd
```

You *could* try to rewrite this as a for in loop, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: This is entirely true, but I get the distinct impression from the question that the OP knows as much already and for some difficult-to-understand reason intends to do otherwise regardless.

Answer (score 2):

With bash 4.0 or newer, you can store these items in an associative array, and iterate over that array with a `for` loop.

```
# prep work: storing in an associative array per field
declare -A homes=( ) shells=( )
while IFS=: read -r user _ _ home shell _; do
  [[ $user = "#"* || ! $user ]] && continue # skip comments, empty lines
  homes[$user]=$home
  shells[$user]=$shell
done </etc/passwd # or < <(getent passwd), to work on LDAP or NIS systems as well
```

...thereafter:

```
# the actual for-based iteration, as requested.
# loop over associative array keys, then look up the values
for user in "${!shells[@]}"; do
  echo "Found $user with shell ${shells[$user]}, home ${homes[$user]}"
done
```

Obviously, this is a bunch of extra work, and it would only fall into the realm of good practices if you had a compelling reason for it; sticking to the `while read` loop is generally the best practice.